# How can I estimate optimal cut-off using linear regression-models

Tags: r, regression, residuals, fitting

To build two linear regression model, (dependant var : B, independant vars : A1, A2, A3) I have to set the cut point of A1. (high A1 and low A2) I want to pick up the model*s*(a model for high A1, and the other for low A2) with with the lowest residual sums of square*s*

In summary, How I can get the optimal cut-off point to get best linear regression models for each groups?

The article I am trying to replicate is below, that description is all. A is dep Var, and B is ind var. "Considered two linear regression models, one for subjects below a certain level of A and the other for subjects above that level. To determine the specific cutoffs, we fitted the two linear regression models described above and calculated the sums of squares of residuals (=observed B - estimated B) from the two models for each level of A. The models with the lowest residual sums of squares were our best models, and the corresponding level of A were defined as the optimal cutoff values."

Url for the article is : http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00223-012-9669-3

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Categorizing variables is not usually a good idea.

Comment: Dear Peter, I want to calculate the odds ratio and conduct logistic regression with the group based on new cut-off.

Comment: Why would you do that when you have a continuous measure already? Hardly ever a good idea.

Comment: It sounds like a better method might be spline regression; but that article did stuff I don't recommend

Comment: the link is to a biomedical journal article. They often use cut-points to provide clinically useful thresholds, with the understanding that you're trading a bit of statistical quality for a bit of clinical utility.

Comment: @charles Thanks, did you saw any previous study adopted this kind of fitting to get optimal cutoff point?

Comment: @JuneKang  I haven't seen something like this. I'm off campus so can't access article. But as someone mentions in your other question it sound a lot like what the -segmented- package does. For that package you have to provide the number of cut-points. If you don't have a preset number this can sort of be dealt with by running a number of cut-points(1-5) and comparing AIC and choosing best model.